Why in flet ft.ChartAxis (ft.LineChart) isn't it posible to use some values?
I have made a chart, the problem here is that, ChartAxisLabel value doesn't work for a lot of values, or at least I don't understand the pattern, I have a tuple with divisions I want to place in the label, and the tuple is always in this format with same separation:[21, 29, 37, 45, 53]. I thought that was the problem before, but it doesn't work yet, the only label I get plotted is the first one, here is the code:
*** Have seen even more weird things, in this case:[2,3,4,5,6] it works fine,  but with largers number it doesn't work.
chart = ft.LineChart(
    data_series=data,
    #border=ft.border.all(2, ft.colors.with_opacity(0.2, ft.colors.ON_SURFACE)),
    horizontal_grid_lines=ft.ChartGridLines(
        interval=interval, color=ft.colors.with_opacity(0.2, ft.colors.ON_SURFACE), width=1
    ),
    vertical_grid_lines=ft.ChartGridLines(
        interval=1, color=ft.colors.with_opacity(0.2, ft.colors.ON_SURFACE), width=1
    ),
    left_axis=ft.ChartAxis(
        labels=[
            ft.ChartAxisLabel(
                value=divisions[0],
                label=ft.Text(divisions[0], size=13, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD,color=fontColor, font_family="Poppins")
            ),
            ft.ChartAxisLabel(
                value=divisions[1],
                label=ft.Text(divisions[1], size=13, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD,color=fontColor, font_family="Poppins")
            ),
            ft.ChartAxisLabel(
                value=divisions[2],
                label=ft.Text(divisions[2], size=13, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD,color=fontColor, font_family="Poppins"),
            ),
            ft.ChartAxisLabel(
                value=divisions[3],
                label=ft.Text(divisions[3], size=13, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD,color=fontColor, font_family="Poppins"),
            ),
            ft.ChartAxisLabel(
                value=divisions[4],
                label=ft.Text(divisions[4], size=13, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD,color=fontColor, font_family="Poppins"),
            )
        ],
        labels_size=40,
    ),
    tooltip_bgcolor=backgroundColor,
    min_y=yLabel[0],
    max_y=yLabel[1]+ 0.2*(yLabel[1]-yLabel[0]),
    min_x=0,
    max_x=len(estimated)-1,
    # animate=5000,
    

)

Here you can see in the image that the only label visible is the first one divisions
